# Left joins on the same table

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jpa

I'm using JPA Query Criteria to build a query with a join on the same table. The table looks like below.

```
Table A

Id  EventType        

A    Start                        
A    Start
A    End
B    Start
C    Start
C    End
```

I want to find out all rows whose EventType is Start and does not have EventType End for the same Id.
In SQL: I got this with joins like this below:

```
   select DISTINCT *
     from (select *
             from A
            where Id='A'
              AND EventType = 'Start') startEventTable 
LEFT JOIN (select *
             from A
            where Id='A'
              AND EventType = 'endEvent') endEventTable 
       ON (startEventTable.Id = endEventTable.Id) 
    WHERE endEventTable.Id IS NULL;
```

I could not realize this in JPA

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> r1 = cq.from(A.class);
SubQuery sq1 = cq.subquery(A.class);
SubQuery sq2 = cq.subquery(A.class);
Root<A> r2 = sql.from(A.class);
Root<A> r3 = sq2.from(A.class);
sq1.where(<predicate>);
sq2.where(<predicate>);

cq.where(cb.and(cb,exists(sq1), cb.exists(sq2).not()));
New TypedQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

This fails with multiple path exceptions. I'm new to JPA queries, request someone to help here.

Comment: You don't need to do this with subqueries, which might be giving you the problem.  What the heck is `<predicate>`?  You also have at least one other syntax error in there.

Comment: There is no such thing as a left inner join. A join is *either* a left join *or* an inner join.

Comment: <predicate> is cb.equal(<some condition>);
There could be some syntax errors alright but I want to understand how to achieve this.. If subqueries is not the way to go, how to realize this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of these simpler and faster queries:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *  -- you probably don't need DISTINCT
FROM   A
WHERE  Id = 'A'
AND    EventType = 'Start'
AND    NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   A a1
    WHERE  a1.Id = A.Id
    AND    EventType = 'endEvent'
    );
```

Or

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT *  -- you probably don't need DISTINCT
FROM   A
LEFT   JOIN A a1 ON a1.Id = A.Id
                AND a1.EventType = 'endEvent'
WHERE  A.Id = 'A'
AND    A.EventType = 'Start'
AND    a1.Id IS NULL;
```

Details:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 0):

You can express equivalent query in JPA:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE Id='A' AND EventType = 'Start'
  AND Id NOT IN (
        SELECT Id from A
        WHERE Id='A'
          AND EventType = 'endEvent')
```

using [this](http://techblog.troyweb.com/index.php/2012/05/writing-strongly-typed-not-in-subqueries-with-jpa-criteriabuilder/) approach.